# Encoding with HttpClient

Tags: windows-8, .net-4.5

I am using the HttpClient class in Windows 8. With Windows Phone, I use
the WebClient class in combination with encoding to get the right encoding.

```
WebClient xml = new WebClient();
xml.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
```

In Windows 8 it is looks like this:

```
HttpClient xml = new HttpClient();
HttpResponseMessage response = await xml.GetAsync(uri);                    
responsetext = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

How can I add a encoding to support German (umlaute)?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have time to test right now, but have you tried using the [HttpContent.ReadAsByteArrayAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpcontent.readasbytearrayasync%28VS.110%29.aspx) method (rather than ReadAsStringAsync) and encoding the resulting byte[] into ISO-8859-1 separately?

Answer (score 1):

Change ReadAsStringAsync to ReadAsBufferAsync and parse result with required encoding

```
var buffer = await response.Content.ReadAsBufferAsync();
byte [] rawBytes = new byte[buffer.Length];
using (var reader = DataReader.FromBuffer(buffer))
{
    reader.ReadBytes(rawBytes);
}

var res = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(rawBytes, 0, rawBytes.Length);
```